# Arduino "RGB" Light not Blinking

Tags: c++, arduino

I just want to know that for RGB light to work on Arduino , is there any special code other than this

```
int rPin = 13;
int gPin = 12;
int bPin = 11;
String msg1 = "Enter the color : ";
String inpt;
void setup() {
  pinMode(rPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(gPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bPin,HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(rPin,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(gPin,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(bPin,HIGH);
}
```

RGB is not doing anything right now..

Comment: Typo `pinMode(bPin,HIGH)`?

Comment: in ```setup()``` function, change the pinMode for bPin from ```HIGH``` to ```OUTPUT```.

Comment: Didnt work out either

Comment: Are you sure that your circuitry is correct?

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes i tried to to add normal led it worked

Comment: Maybe your rgb led has different electrical requirements than your normal one? Or you've connected it incorrectly?

Comment: @AlanBirtles okkk :)

Answer (score 0):

i guess there are some things missing out. First, you don't change the states of the leds to OFF in the loop. And second there's no delays. Even if you chnage the states, you must have some delays to see the blinking. here's a code I suggest, try it and see if the result is what you want :

```
int rPin = 13;
int gPin = 12;
int bPin = 11;
int period = 500; //blinking period in ms
//String msg1 = "Enter the color : "; not used in this example
//String inpt;
void setup() {
  pinMode(rPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(gPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bPin,HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(rPin,HIGH);
  delay(period);
  digitalWrite(rPin,LOW);

  digitalWrite(gPin,HIGH);
  delay(period);
  digitalWrite(gPin,LOW);

  digitalWrite(bPin,HIGH);
  delay(period);
  digitalWrite(bPin,LOW);

}
```

and of course you might put different periods for each led, depending on your application.